# Post request returns 400 Bad Request in RobotFramework

Tags: post, robotframework, http-status-code-400

I've been using a RobotFramework for sending a POST request
My code is the following :

```
*** Settings ***
Library  RequestsLibrary
Library  JSONLibrary
Library  Collections


*** Variables ***
${API_Base_Endpoint}    http://thetestingworldapi.com/




*** Test Cases ***
Post_Req_Test
    Create Session          AddData            ${API_Base_Endpoint}
    ${body}=                create dictionary   first_name=Tester1  middle_name=NAN  last_name=Tester2  date_of_birth=01/01/1999
    LOG TO CONSOLE          ${body}
    ${header}=              create dictionary   Content-Type=application/json
    ${response}=            post on session     AddData    api/studentsDetails     data=${body}  headers=${header}
```

But from some reason I'm getting a "HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: [http://thetestingworldapi.com/api/studentsDetails"](http://thetestingworldapi.com/api/studentsDetails%22)

I've tried to send same request via Postman , and it works with no issues.

Any ideas what may go wrong ?

Comment: The body needs to be serialized to JSON, its essentially the same as this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142412/how-to-rest-api-with-put-method-via-robot-framework/70147308#70147308

Comment: @MatthewKing Thank you ! it worked , I just wondering how no one performs serialization in every tutorial I saw. Thanks again

Comment: With the help of @MatthewKing I was referenced to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142412/how-to-rest-api-with-put-method-via-robot-framework/70147308#70147308)
Worked for me

Comment: based on your comment, I did some digging and it seems that if you pass the body to json e.g. json=${body} instead of data=${body}, you won't need the serialization line I suggested

Comment: Yep , worked as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @MatthewKing I was referenced to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142412/how-to-rest-api-with-put-method-via-robot-framework/70147308#70147308) solution Worked for me